# Read Data Across USB Port

Tags: usb

I'm playing around with an old Trackball I purchased from Sparkfun. My trackball powers on, but it doesn't actually work. All the lights flash, and it indicates that I've left and right clicked, but the mouse on my screen does nothing.
I want to monitor the input values of the trackball across a USB port so I can track down the problem. I've looked for code I can run on Netbeans, but came up empty handed.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified what OS are you using. You need dedicated driver for this device. In case of Linux you would need to write your own driver for the kernel. But first you need to have specification of protocol which this device is using over usb and also usb protocol itself. It is quite sophisticated task to do...

In case of Windows there are some programs for dumping transmission between usb host (PC) and device (trackball), but at the moment I can't give you any name of such program. In case of Linux you can dump the transmission using tcpdump or wireshark commands.